# Is there any way to scroll absolute shapes in java scroll pane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, absolute

I have drawn ellipses by giving absolute position say at x=300 and y=12. But whenever I scroll pane it repaints image after the visible portion. I want positions to be reactive to scroll pane origin

[image]

Comment: *relative to scroll pane origin

Comment: You can edit your post with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58920743/edit) link!

Comment: @csabinho `[edit]` in a comment auto-expands to [edit].

Comment: It seems like the code is not calling the super method when painting. For anything further than that guess, post a [mre].